# What is this popular website template called?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, website-design, responsive-webdesign

I see that many popular website now implement a similar template. Do you know its name?

- https://www.braintreepayments.com/
- http://www.techsoft3d.com/
- http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either achieve (customize) that from a basic bootstrap template for your favorite CMS (because this kind of design is very basic and common), or pick a template like Strapped (really basic, require some work), or Creative, MeetGavern, or Simplicity, from GavickPro (www.gavick.com) for Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

These three websites doesn't have a particular template for code.

This is not because they have a similar rendering (full screen rendering...) that they use a template like a CMS or something else.